# SDL_SetWindowSize gives a new window, that can't be written to

Tags: sdl-2

In the program below, `SDL_SetWindowSize` *does* make the window itself bigger... but it *doesn't* let `SDL_RenderClear` (or other functions) display anything in that new area.

The platform is CentOS running on VMWare.  I don't get this problem in my Visual Studio version, FWIW.

In this screenshot, the window with the grey top bar is the new window created by the resize; it's cleared to red, but only in the area delimited by the old size. 
[image]

I know I could create the window the right size from the beginning, but I really do need the ability to resize later.

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_ttf.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>

SDL_Window*   sdlWindow;
SDL_Renderer* sdlRenderer;

class myException {};

void initialize ()
{
  if (SDL_Init (SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) < 0)
    throw myException ();  

  sdlWindow = SDL_CreateWindow ("",     
                 SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                 640, 480,
                 0);        
  if (! sdlWindow) throw myException ();

  int rendererIndex = -1, rendererFlags =  0;
  sdlRenderer = SDL_CreateRenderer (sdlWindow, rendererIndex, rendererFlags);

  if (! sdlRenderer) throw myException ();

  SDL_ClearError ();
}

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
  initialize ();

  SDL_SetWindowSize (sdlWindow, 800, 400);

  SDL_SetRenderDrawColor (sdlRenderer, 255, 0, 0, 255); //now we'll clear to red

  SDL_RenderClear   (sdlRenderer);
  SDL_RenderPresent (sdlRenderer); //update screen now

  SDL_Delay (2000);                 //Delay, then quit
  SDL_Quit ();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can't reproduce, but two points: 1) you can't mix SDL renderer and window surface. E.g. in my (probably) more recent SDL2 release your test program fails when trying to get window surface - because window already have a renderer associated with it. 2) in most cases you have to flush event queue regularly or at least after resize/redraw. draw&delay is not a way to display things.

Comment: I'm happy to know that window surface is not needed, and have removed it entirely.  I also added `SDL_FlushEvents   (SDL_FIRSTEVENT, SDL_LASTEVENT);` immediately after the resize.  The behavior's not changing yet.

Comment: Not that simple - `SDL_FlushEvents` doesn't call `SDL_PumpEvents`, you have to call it yourself. But the bigger problem remains anyway - you can't draw something, say 'present' and wait - there are just too many things that can go wrong, especially with double buffering and compositing window manager. At the very least you should read events that window manager sends you and redraw when it says you need to. For a beginner it would be *much* simplier to use proper event loop and redraw unconditionally.

Comment: Hm.  There must be a reason to have SDL_Delay.  Are you suggesting I give up on it and build my own, which processes all events until a set time passes?  I can do that, but I hate to reinvent the wheel (and don't care so much for busy waiting).

Comment: Absolutely not, but at the same time in order to display things you need to redraw when window manager asks you too - other way it don't have good data to show to user and result may be, well, - anything. Drawing at once and expecting image to be shown for N seconds later is wrong, even if it sometimes works. There are `SDL_WaitEvent` and `SDL_WaitEventTimeout` for purposes that you've described. However since SDL is used almost exclusively for games - you're far less likely to find information about that approach, that is why I recommended to stick to "common" approach for now.

Comment: And "common" for games is redrawing unconditionally (which with vsync still limits you to e.g. 60 frames per second). That way you don't have to worry about when to redraw, since you redraw anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The rendering surface is invalidated on windows resize, quote from [SDL wiki on SDL_GetWindowSurface](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetWindowSurface):

> This surface will be invalidated if the window is resized. After resizing a window this function must be called again to return a valid surface.

So you must get window surface again after resizing window, in general.

Comment: That makes sense, and I shouldn't have missed that.  So I added code to free the current surface and create a new one (the OP is now so edited).  I'm not seeing a difference in the behavior, though.

Comment: @TopologicalSort not really. It was incorrect in the first place since [documentation](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetWindowSurface) says "You may not combine this with 3D or the rendering API on this window. ", and now it is worse because it says "This surface will be freed when the window is destroyed. Do not free this surface." and "This surface will be invalidated if the window is resized.".

Comment: I have removed all references to the surface from `SDL_GetWIndowSurface`, so although that was undoubtedly wrong, it's not a problem any more.  OP is now so edited.  Behavior remains unchanged, alas.